# Algorithm for possible arrays of two letters with constraint

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I want to write an algorithm for finding every possible array of dimension k formed by combinations of the two letters "n" and "o", but in none of the combinations I would have two "n" next to each other.
In example, if k = 4 :

Nooo

Noon

Nono

Onoo

Onon

Oono

Ooon

My try is a function that makes out of an array [n,o,o,o,....o] a list another arrays with an "n" every 2 records, then calling it again for the array [n,o,n,o,....,o] recursively

but I am missing the cases like [n,o,o,o,n,o,o,n,...o,o] when there is a a break of multiple ''o'' between the ''n''

Thank you for your help

Comment: What programming language do you have in mind?

Comment: What did you try? Where are the problems?

Comment: I am trying to write it un vb .net, but any language or algorithm would be apreciated.

Comment: Please provide examples of the code you have written so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, this might not be the best forum to ask this question in, https://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place.

Comment: Do you want to list them, or do you just want to count them?

Comment: @admcfajn Algorithm questions are perfectly fine here, that's what the [algorithm] tag is for; no need to run to Computer Science. (That being said, "I want to write an algorithm that does x" is not a great question.)

Comment: I suggest you write a recursive algorithm where at each recursion level you add either "o" or "no"; or "o" or "n" for the last character.

Comment: @admcfajn here is my code for the first function    Public Sub PossibleA(a As Byte(), k As Integer)
        Dim l As Integer = a.Length
        Dim t, r As Byte()
        Dim i As Integer

        ReDim r(n)
        Array.Copy(a, r, l)
        i = k
        While i > 1
            ReDim t(n)
            r(i) = 1
            Array.Copy(r, t, l)
            MatriceOfNo.Add(t)
            i = i - 2
        End While
    End Sub

Comment: @m69 yes this was my try, a function that makes out of an array [n,o,o,o,....o] a list another arrays with an "n" every 2 records, but I am missing the cases like [n,o,o,o,n,o,o,n,...o,o] when there is a couple of ''o'' before the next "n"

Comment: @Ryan  I want to list them, in term of number of cases, I think it's in the order of 2*pow(2,k/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> Combinations(int length, char? current = null)
{
    var output = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<char>>();
    if (length == 1)
    {
        if (current != 'n')
        {
            output = output.Concat(new[] { new[] { 'n' } });
        }
        output = output.Concat(new[] { new[] { 'o' } });
    }
    else if (length > 1)
    {
        if (current != 'n')
        {
            output = output.Concat(Combinations(length - 1, 'n').Select(xs => new[] { 'n' }.Concat(xs)));
        }
        output = output.Concat(Combinations(length - 1, 'o').Select(xs => new[] { 'o' }.Concat(xs)));
    }
    return output;
}
```

For `Combinations(4)` I get:

```
nono 
noon 
nooo 
onon 
onoo 
oono 
ooon 
oooo
```

Comment: Tank you very much, how do you call this function from the main sub (I searched how to make it run since yesterday with no luck, looping for every element of the ienumerable then .tostring returns "system.string[]"

Comment: @Rachid - It returns a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>>` so you have to iterate twice in one fashion or another. Try something like `foreach (var outer in Combinations(4)) Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", outer));`.

Comment: @ Enigmatvity It works :) Thank you very much for your help